# Can I use JAXRS annotations(for example @Produces) in an interface class in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to create an interface class in Grails and implement that in a resource. I wanted to use the @Produces annotation in the interface class and use(implement) that in my resources class. I created my interface in src/groovy. But, it doesn't like the @Produces annotation, gives syntax error. My interface is something like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Produces

public interface annotationInterface {
@Produces(['application/xml','application/json'])
}
```

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: What syntax error? Does the annotation take a List?

Comment: It gives "Groovy:unexpected token @@" error. The error points to @Produces annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Your annotation does not annotate anything, that is why the compiler complains. javax.ws.rs.Produces can annotate methods or classes, so in your case I would think that

```
import javax.ws.rs.Produces

@Produces(['application/xml','application/json'])
public interface annotationInterface {

}
```

I cannot say if it makes sense though, because annotations are not inherited, so any class implementing the interface won't have that annotation. So unless there is a lookup for this annotation on implementing interfaces and/or super classes it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you used the [Jax-rs plug-in](http://www.grails.org/plugin/jaxrs) ?  If not, there will be a class path problem.

Comment: Yes, I am using jax-rs plugin. It works fine if I create a super class instead of an interface. It doesn't like the syntax in the interface class. Thanks.